# How to set different Deployment target for iPhone and iPad in a Universal Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have just released a iPhone application. it supports from iOS 4.2. now i want to add a iPad support using iOS 5 features.

Will i able to set the different deployment target for iPad(iOS 5.0) and iPhone(iOS 4.2) in a Universal application.

Thanks
Sasikumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only one deployment target can be applied to all devices per app. If your universal app requires iOS 5 features, the deployment target must be no less than 5.0 for both devices. If you want to support 4.2 on the iPhone, you have to support 4.2 on the iPad as well.